# Как вернуть старую цветовую палитру?

Tags: поддержка, дизайн, доступность

Учитывая множественные дефекты и проблемы запуска **[новых цветов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/393939/new-colors-launched?cb=1)**, возможно ли временно вернуть старые цвета для ruSO, используя различный пользовательский инструментарий?

В данном контексте "пользовательский инструментарий" означает программы, настройки или средства, которые пользователи могут использовать для управления интерфейсом веб-сайта.

Comment: Вызвано данное желание тем, что есть [очень раздражающий момент в секции "Похожие" для тёмной неконтрастной темы](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/393999/1370694)

Comment: Ну можно свою css-ку накидать

Comment: @aepot в принципе я туда и начал копать, нашёл класс в стилях который отвечает за этот цвет, просто я не особо вебер чтобы понимать, как поверх существующего стиля собственный накатывать и какой инструментарий для этого нужен

Comment: Расширение для браузера, которому указываешь адрес сайта и css. https://www.tampermonkey.net/

Answer (score 2):

По рекомендации [@aepot](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/373567/aepot) было принято следующее персональное решение для цвета шрифта цифр в секции "Похожие" и "Связанные":

1. [Установите расширение tampermonkey.net](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)
2. Создайте следующий скрипт

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Изменение стиля элементов на сайте
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Изменить цвет всех элементов с классом answer-votes на hsl(0,0%,0%)
// @author       You
// @match        https://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Найти все элементы с классом "answer-votes answered-accepted" и изменить их цвет
    const elementsToChange = document.querySelectorAll('.answer-votes.answered-accepted');
    if (elementsToChange) {
        elementsToChange.forEach(element => {
            element.style.color = 'hsl(0,0%,0%)';
        });
    }
})();
```

3. Сохраните и перезагрузите страницу ruSO.

Результат до:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат после работы скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]